# How to record a click event for an image acting as a button in Selenium?

Tags: java, html, forms, selenium-rc, onsubmit

In my application, I have got an image as a button. When I record the button click event in Selenium IDE and replay it, i merely plays it back but the click event is not actually submitting the value

Ex: The submit button (which is an image) should actually submit the value to database. But when I check in the database, the value is not added there

***Element Value***

```
<input width="98" vspace="3" type="Image" height="15" border="0" 
id="Image1" src="images/butt_submit.gif" value="Submit" name="Submit">
```

***Selenium Code***

```
selenium.click("//input[@id='Image1']");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

Please assist.

Thanking you!

HG

Comment: Try using `selenium.click(name=Submit);` and see if the data is getting reflected in the database. Let us know if still you are facing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm still facing this issue. Manually clicking on the button will submit the value. But when I run the selenium code it does not give any errors, but the value is actually not submitted :(

Comment: Are you getting any Error after running the selenium Code?
For Ex:- `Element not found` May be Submit button is present in a frame. Did you check for that?

Comment: that's the thing.. it does not throw any errors, the testcase get completed without any errors, but the form/value is not submitted. If I add the waitForPageToLoad command the page merely times out, the button click does not work. Bt if i do it manually it wirks. I still couldn't figure this out. the button is inside a table. if so does it behave in a different way? P.S.: I'm not an epert in selenium-rc therefore, I welcome any help! :)

Comment: If it is not confidential, can you share the app link, so that we can debug the issue?

Comment: send the link to my mail id hemu216@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with Selenium/IDE not clicking the image. The code you're using (in HTML) will not submit the form data even if you did it manually. Did you check that first?

Anyway, if you want to use an **image as the submit action** for a form, add an **`onclick`** event for the image to submit the form. See [this example on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) for `form.submit`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function formSubmit()
{
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Submit form">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

They are using a button here but you can use that for your image.

More about HTML Forms basics: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply.
Yes manually clicking on it will submit the value.
I'm unable to change the HTML code in the application in code level.
Is there anyway to do that in Selenium code?